# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Tags: c, linux

I am very very very new to Unix, but experienced in C. I wasn't sure whether this Message fits the Unix forum (if there's one), or C. But, since it is a compiling Error, I felt it fits here best.

I did a "make", compilation, to a program called ioquake3. I get these errors. I tried to google them. It seems that these errors are caused by double inclusions, or something of the sort.
I tried endlessly to see how to make the write edits to the code. But, I couldn't fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../qcommon/q_shared.h"
#include "../qcommon/qcommon.h"

#ifdef WIN32
#define DEFAULT_CURL_LIB "libcurl-3.dll"
#elif defined(MACOS_X)
#define DEFAULT_CURL_LIB "libcurl.dylib"
#else
#define DEFAULT_CURL_LIB "libcurl.so.4"
#define ALTERNATE_CURL_LIB "libcurl.so.3"
#endif

#ifdef USE_LOCAL_HEADERS
  //#include &lt;../libcurl/curl/curl.h&gt;
#else
  //#include &lt;../libcurl/curl/curl.h&gt;
#endif


#ifdef USE_CURL_DLOPEN
extern char* (*qcurl_version)(void);
extern cvar_t *cl_cURLLib;
extern CURL* (*qcurl_easy_init)(void);
extern CURLcode (*qcurl_easy_setopt)(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...);
`enter code here`extern CURLcode (*qcurl_easy_perform)(CURL *curl);
extern void (*qcurl_easy_cleanup)(CURL *curl);
extern CURLcode (*qcurl_easy_getinfo)(CURL *curl, CURLINFO info, ...);
extern void (*qcurl_easy_reset)(CURL *curl);
extern const char *(*qcurl_easy_strerror)(CURLcode);

extern CURLM* (*qcurl_multi_init)(void);
extern CURLMcode (*qcurl_multi_add_handle)(CURLM *multi_handle,
                        CURL *curl_handle);
extern CURLMcode (*qcurl_multi_remove_handle)(CURLM *multi_handle,
                        CURL *curl_handle);
extern CURLMcode (*qcurl_multi_fdset)(CURLM *multi_handle,
                        fd_set *read_fd_set,
                        fd_set *write_fd_set,
                        fd_set *exc_fd_set,
                        int *max_fd);
extern CURLMcode (*qcurl_multi_perform)(CURLM *multi_handle,
                        int *running_handles);
extern CURLMcode (*qcurl_multi_cleanup)(CURLM *multi_handle);
extern CURLMsg *(*qcurl_multi_info_read)(CURLM *multi_handle,
                        int *msgs_in_queue);
extern const char *(*qcurl_multi_strerror)(CURLMcode);
#else
#define qcurl_version curl_version

#define qcurl_easy_init curl_easy_init
#define qcurl_easy_setopt curl_easy_setopt
#define qcurl_easy_perform curl_easy_perform
#define qcurl_easy_cleanup curl_easy_cleanup
#define qcurl_easy_getinfo curl_easy_getinfo
#define qcurl_easy_duphandle curl_easy_duphandle
#define qcurl_easy_reset curl_easy_reset
#define qcurl_easy_strerror curl_easy_strerror

#define qcurl_multi_init curl_multi_init
#define qcurl_multi_add_handle curl_multi_add_handle
#define qcurl_multi_remove_handle curl_multi_remove_handle
#define qcurl_multi_fdset curl_multi_fdset
#define qcurl_multi_perform curl_multi_perform
#define qcurl_multi_cleanup curl_multi_cleanup
#define qcurl_multi_info_read curl_multi_info_read
#define qcurl_multi_strerror curl_multi_strerror
#endif

qboolean CL_cURL_Init( void );
void CL_cURL_Shutdown( void );
void CL_cURL_BeginDownload( const char *localName, const char *remoteURL );
void CL_cURL_PerformDownload( void );
void CL_cURL_Cleanup( void );
```

Errors:

```
make[2]: `build/release-linux-x86_64/ioq3ded.x86_64' is up to date.
CC code/client/cl_cgame.c
In file included from code/client/cl_cgame.c:24:
code/client/client.h:40: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:41: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:41: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:42: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:42: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:43: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:44: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:45: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:46: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
code/client/client.h:48: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:49: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:49: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:51: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:51: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:53: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:53: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:58: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:58: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:60: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:60: error: expected ')' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:61: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
code/client/client.h:63: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
In file included from code/client/cl_cgame.c:24:
code/client/client.h:264: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'CURL'
code/client/cl_cgame.c: In function 'CL_GetServerCommand':
code/client/cl_cgame.c:276: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'demoplaying'
code/client/cl_cgame.c: In function 'CL_InitCGame':
code/client/cl_cgame.c:751: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'demoplaying'
code/client/cl_cgame.c: In function 'CL_CGameRendering':
code/client/cl_cgame.c:799: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'demoplaying'
code/client/cl_cgame.c: In function 'CL_AdjustTimeDelta':
code/client/cl_cgame.c:834: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'demoplaying'
code/client/cl_cgame.c: In function 'CL_FirstSnapshot':
code/client/cl_cgame.c:900: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoBaseTime'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:919: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexInitialized'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:921: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexEncoderBits'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:922: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexEncoderBits'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:924: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexEncoder'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:926: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexEncoder'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:927: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexFrameSize'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:928: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexEncoder'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:929: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexSampleRate'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:931: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexPreprocessor'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:931: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexFrameSize'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:932: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexSampleRate'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:935: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexPreprocessor'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:939: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexPreprocessor'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:943: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexDecoderBits'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:944: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexDecoderBits'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:945: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexDecoder'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:946: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'voipIgnore'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:947: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'voipGain'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:949: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'speexInitialized'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:950: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'voipMuteAll'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:953: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'voipTarget1'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:953: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'voipTarget2'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:953: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'voipTarget3'
code/client/cl_cgame.c: In function 'CL_SetCGameTime':
code/client/cl_cgame.c:969: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'demoplaying'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:972: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'firstDemoFrameSkipped'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:973: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'firstDemoFrameSkipped'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1006: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'demoplaying'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1045: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'demoplaying'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1061: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoStart'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1062: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoStart'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1062: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoLastFrame'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1063: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoMinDuration'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1064: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoMaxDuration'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1067: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoLastFrame'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1068: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoLastFrame'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1071: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoFrames'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1073: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoMaxDuration'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1074: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoMaxDuration'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1076: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoMinDuration'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1077: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoMinDuration'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1083: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoDurations'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1083: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoFrames'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1087: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoFrames'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1088: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoBaseTime'
code/client/cl_cgame.c:1088: error: 'clientConnection_t' has no member named 'timeDemoFrames'
make[2]: *** [build/release-linux-x86_64/client/cl_cgame.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/r/home7/yasir/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/best_linux_20111012/ioquake3dev_clean'
make[1]: *** [targets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/r/home7/yasir/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/best_linux_20111012/ioquake3dev_clean'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Language C
Linux

Comment: Perhaps you should check out the build guide for ioquake3 [here](http://wiki.ioquake3.org/Building_ioquake3)?

Comment: Code for horror animation? I scare!

Answer (score 7):

In `gcc`, the error:

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
```

is often associated with an `typedef` that isn't in scope when you use it. For example, the following program:

```
mytype fn(int n) { return (mytype)n; }
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

generates this error when you try to compile it:

```
prog.c:2: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'fn'
```

If you insert the line `typedef int mytype;` at the top of the file, it compiles okay.

Now it's a little hard to discern which *precise* lines in your code map to the line numbers listed in the errors, but my first guess would be that you do not include the CURL header files. This seems to be the case as you have lines like:

```
extern CURL* (*qcurl_easy_init)(void);
```

but nowhere do you appear to include a header file that would give you a definition for the `CURL` type.

You *do* have the following code:

```
#ifdef USE_LOCAL_HEADERS
  //#include &lt;../libcurl/curl/curl.h&gt;
#else
  //#include &lt;../libcurl/curl/curl.h&gt;
#endif
```

but this looks like you've copied these from a "view source" representation of a web page and just commented them out when they didn't work. What you probably need is something like:

```
  #include <../libcurl/curl/curl.h>
```

adjusting, of course, for the *actual* location of the header file.

Comment: Thank u so much..i was trying to debug similar issue for an hour, your answer solved it.